# Does it matter if I upgrade my entire conveyor belt, or can I just upgrade entry-points?

Tags: mindustry

In **Mindustry**, you use conveyor belts to transport your materials around the map.  You can eventually construct Titanium Conveyor Belts, which move items faster while the item is on that piece of the belt.

However, as each piece of material is a physical object to other materials, and existing material can block new material from entering the belt, so they can be compacted together to remove excess space, does it matter if I upgrade my entire conveyor belt line or can I get away with just upgrading the entry-points?

Since items are only blocked from moving onto the belt when entering it perpendicularly, you can theoretically smash as many items into a belt that you want (so long as it's not coming from a perpendicular direction). Doing so essentially creates an "opening" as the material gets pushed further into the line, allowing space for new material to enter the belt from a perpendicular entry belt.

So, the question is, is there a point in upgrading the entire line, or does cramming my unupgraded belts work just as well?

Comment: I dont play that game but I would guess that the same thing as Internet Network applies: Your conveyor belt will only be as fast as the slowest part of it. Example: If all your conveyor belt segments bring the element from the start of the segment to the finish in 1 second (and a piece of belt can only have one piece on it at once), but one non upgraded part takes 2 second, at the end of the belt you will only get one component every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since items are only blocked from moving onto the belt when entering it perpendicularly, you can theoretically smash as many items into a belt that you want (so long as it's not coming from a perpendicular direction)

After some trial-and-error, I've discovered that this line is actually incorrect.  By smashing a bunch of items from a faster belt into a slower belt, both going in the same direction, I discovered the faster belt near the end was only able to push items as fast as the belt in front of it.  This means that each material does, in fact, have a solid size that can't be compressed, giving a very real reason for major segments of the belt to be upgraded.

That being said, there doesn't appear to be a reason to upgrade a belt until after the belt is packed full and the suppliers for those belts are delayed from producing material due to its clogged belt lines.  So you don't actually have to upgrade much more than the entry/breakpoints and whatever lines are full.